# Uncaught TypeError: utils.formatPriceLocale is not a function

Tags: javascript, frontend, frontend-error, magento2.4.5

I am upgrading to 2.4.5-p1

I can't seem to figure out how to resolve this error.

```
price-box.js:153 Uncaught TypeError: utils.formatPriceLocale is not a function
at $.<computed>.<computed>.<anonymous> (price-box.js:153:41)
at underscore.js:723:29
at Function.each (underscore.js:1335:17)
at $.<computed>.<computed>.reDrawPrices (price-box.js:148:15)
at $.<computed>.<computed>.reloadPrice (widget.js:132:25)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5430:49)
at elemData.handle (jquery.js:5234:47)
at Object.trigger (jquery.js:8719:28)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js:8797:30)
at Function.each (jquery.js:385:35)
```

Here is the function that is not working:

price.formatted = utils.formatPriceLocale(price.final, priceFormat);

Comment: Check you check override file price-utils.js in any custom module or theme? 
formatPriceLocale is not exist before 2.4.5 so add it on your file and also add in return.

Comment: That was the issue thank you Rutvik

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when I upgraded one of the website from Magento2.4.4 to Magento2.4.5-p2. After investing lots of hours I debugged the issue so I thought to share my findings here so that It may help other developers with same issue quickly.
If you see **Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils** js file, you will see a function named as **formatPriceLocale()**, which was not available before Magento2.4.5 so find out all js files overriding Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils in the theme or any custom or third party modules and add the same function to that file from core file. It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I upgraded one of the website from Magento2.4.4 to Magento2.4.5-p2. After investing lots of hours I debugged the issue so I thought to share my findings here so that It may help other developers with same issue quickly.
If you see **Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils** js file, you will see a function named as **formatPriceLocale()**, which was not available before Magento2.4.5 so find out all js files overriding Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils in the theme or any custom or third party modules and add the same function that file from core file. It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar error.
Find the module that overrides the price-utils.js file, this module needs to be updated.
For this we used the lillik/magento2-price-decimal module.